# Securing Delphi application SSL traffic from decryption

Tags: drm, license-enforcement

I wrote a VCL app using Delphi10.2. It has a simple activation setup, encrypted key is stored in Kinvey backend. The key to decrypt the encrypted key is hidden in the source code.

Now in order to establish the HTTPS connection, the app needs Indy's ssl files libeay32.dll and ssleay32.dll. They are attached in the same folder with the exe.

My questions are: is it possible somehow to use the DLL files to extract the private key to decrypt the HTTPS traffic? If so, will the attacker be able to dectpyt the encrypted key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The key to decrypt the encrypted key is hidden in the source code.

This is a problem because applications (or its DLL's) can be reverse engineered. Sometimes this is quite easy and other times it may take a lot more effort. Ultimately it can be done.

> Is it possible somehow to use the DLL files to extract the private key to decrypt the HTTPS traffic?

As you stated (or as I understood it), the key that is hidden in the code, is in the executable. As an attacker I would first load the executable in the a debugger and see what happens.

Once the (hidden) key is obtained in order to decrypt the private key, the traffic could be intercepted using Wireshark configured with the private key.

However, if Diffie Hellman key exchange is used, the attacker can not decrypt previously captured traffic, meaning traffic captured before the private key was obtained.

Comment: i see. this is not an easy task for armature crackers i guess.can you advice some debuggers to test . Thank you.

Comment: OllyDBG or Immunity debugger is what I've used in the past.